# Assign QNetworkRequest to the corresponding QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to associate a QNetworkRequest to a QNetworkReply?
It feels not as good practice to create a new QNetworkAccessManager for every request I want to make, partly because the documentation implies that QNetworkManager can execute requests in parallel and I want to reuse the cached connections.

setAttribute will not work, as the documentation says.

Comment: If you want to get the QNetworkRequest that the QNetworReply created then that is already implemented based on the request() method of QNetworkReply: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#request

Comment: Thank you. Thats it :)